# Regex to get previous word followed by a phrase in python

Tags: python, regex, split, python-re, text-extraction

I need to extract the word **local** when it comes before **gun store**. But, the below function is not returning it because of using split. Is there any way to get around this?

Source looks like this: As reported on 30 December 2019, in Maipu, Metropolitan region, a group of at least 10 rioters attempted to loot a local gun store.

Here is the function:

````
    regex_filter = r'local|dozen|several|looted'
    property_key = r"\b(gun store|establishments|supermarket)\b"
    source= source.split()
    for i, w in enumerate(source):
        if (re.search(property_key, w)):
            if re.match(re.compile(regex_filter, flags=re.IGNORECASE), source[i-1]):
                return source[i-1]```
````

Comment: What "way" are you looking for? Why not use ``(\S+)\s+(?:gun store|establishments|supermarket)\b``

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for helping out here, but it's not working, I think the problem is caused by split, it's trying to match gun and store separately

Comment: That is what I am saying, too. Why not use `m = re.search(r'(\S+)\s+(?:gun store|establishments|supermarket)\b', text)` and then `if m: print(m.group(1))`? See https://ideone.com/lxygzY

Comment: Sure @WiktorStribiżew, Will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest extracting the word preceding any of the words listed in `property_key` with

```py
re.search(r"(\S+)\s+(?:gun store|establishments|supermarket)\b", text)
```

Or, if the word is formed with word chars and there can be any whitespace/punctuation between the words:

```py
re.search(r"([^\W_]+)[\W_]+(?:gun store|establishments|supermarket)\b", text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I8OprX/1).

The `(\S+)\s+` matches and captures one or more non-whitespace chars into Group 1 and then matches one or more whitespace chars, while `([^\W_]+)[\W_]+` matches and captures one or more letters or digits into Group 1 and then one or more non-word or underscore chars are matched.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/lxygzY):

```py
import re
rx = r"(\S+)\s+(?:gun store|establishments|supermarket)\b"
text = "As reported on 30 December 2019, in Maipu, Metropolitan region, a group of at least 10 rioters attempted to loot a local gun store."
m = re.search(rx, text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))

# => local
```